# How to configure the github action to deploy docker container to aws elasticbeanstalk multi-container environment

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

Hi I am using github aciton to do my CICD pipline. And I try to deploy multiple docker container to AWS elasticbeanstalk with multiple-container environment.

In my github action, I have already successfully push my docker images to the docker hub. What should I do next in my github action? Should I still deploy the zip file to AWS elasticbeanstalk or something else? Would someone give something guides please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After pushing to Docker Hub, you need to create an authentication file that contains information required to authenticate with the registry using [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private).

Add the `authentication` parameter to the `Dockerrun.aws.json` configuration file

The ElasticBeanstalk multi-container environment only supports hosted images. As a result, you can deploy the `Dockerrun.aws.json` configuration file on it's own without having to create a zip archive of the source code. If you do zip the source code with the configuration file, it becomes available in the EC2 container instances and is accessible in the `/var/app/current/`

Read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html